# Adding Table to Database with Migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I made some changes to my models, these included adding a new field to a class and creating a new class (table), as shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SurveyTool.Models
{
    public class Industry
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

When I `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database`, the new field was added. However, the new table wasn't. I tried the process again and the newest migration is empty.

Why isn't the standard process for adding a new table working?

Thanks!

Comment: You created this class....is it part of your context?

Comment: @mason How would I check?

Comment: You’d look at your context.

Comment: I'm a complete newbie. I'm not sure how to find my context (I'm assuming you mean ApplicationDBContext). Could you point me to an article or tutorial on the topic? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I mean ApplicationDbContext. When generating migrations it's going to look at the objects in the context to know what's changed. So if you created a new class, you probably need to add it to your context in order to get recognized. You should be able to find a tutorial for how EF code first and migrations work with just a little web search.